# Set the whole request url in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-5.0

I have a request, which gives upload url as response body.

```
{
    "uploadUrl": "https://test.com:9000/sample_uploadurl"
}
```

I'm able to extract the `uploadUrl` using JSON extractor.
[image: JSON extractor]

I want to use above upload url to in next http request. How to set the new request here ?

[image]

adding directly doent work, because JMeter prepends http/https before request, in this case we already have https.

> It got failed because it has `https://[https://test.com:9000/sample_uploadurl]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) fields empty except Path, put there the variable and it will be executed

> As a special case, if the path starts with "http://" or "https://" then this is used as the full URL.

example 
[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

The options are in:

1. Put the whole `${UPLOAD_URL}` to "Path" field of the HTTP Request sampler like:

   [image]

   however this approach might be flaky and cause the malfunction of certain configuration elements like [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager). So it's better to go for option 2.
2. Split the `${UPLOAD_URL}` into individual components like protocol, host, port and path.

   - Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) **after** the JSON Extractor
   - Put the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code into "Script" area:

     ```
     URL url = new URL(vars.get('UPLOAD_URL'))

     vars.put('protocol', url.getProtocol())
     vars.put('host', url.getHost())
     vars.put('port', url.getPort() as String)
     vars.put('path', url.getPath())
     ```
   - The above code will generate the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

     [image]
   - So you should be able to use the generated variables in the next HTTP Request sampler:

     [image]