# I am getting the Billdesk URL in the response of booking API, I have to navigate to the URL and make payment on browser. Can we do it using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am new to Jmeter. I am getting the below-mentioned code in the response of the Booking API. I have to click on the 'requestUrl' field. It will redirect me to the browser and opens the billdesk page where I have to make payment. After successfull payment, my booking will be done. Each time we are getting the different URL. Can we do this using Jmeter?

```
"data": {
    "requestUrl": "https://uat.billdesk.com/xyz",
    "redirectUrl": "http:xyz",
    "orderNumber": "5904"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the whole request url in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562861/set-the-whole-request-url-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `requestUrl`
   - JSON Path Expressions: a [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) query matching the request URL, i.e. `$.data.requestUrl`

     [image]
   - Other fields can be left intact:
3. Add HTTP Request sampler after the first request and put `${requestUrl}` into "Path" field:

   [image]
4. That's it, in the runtime the `${requestUrl}` JMeter Variable will be substituted by the value from the previous request JSON response:

   [image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)